# Django attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'is_usable'

Tags: python, django

I got the following error when calling the url in Django.
It's working before, I guess it's related with some accidental changes I made, but I have no idea what they are.

Thanks before for the help,
Robert

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET Request URL: http://localhost:8000/time/ Django Version: 1.2 Python Version: 2.6.1 Installed Applications: ['django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites',  'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.admin',  'djlearn.books'] Installed Middleware: ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback: File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args,
**callback_kwargs) File "/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/djlearn/src/djlearn/../djlearn/views.py" in current_datetime
  16.     return render_to_response('current_datetime.html',{'current_date':now,}) File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args,
**kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs) File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  181.         t = get_template(template_name) File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  157.     template, origin = find_template(template_name) File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  128.             loader = find_template_loader(loader_name) File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template_loader
  111.         if not func.is_usable:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /time/ Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'is_usable'
```

Comment: Can you post the view and template? And git is a fine way of doing incremental, local checkins so that 'some accidental changes' are very easy to locate and recover from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Django is looking for a usable template loader, but is finding something in `settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS` that isn't honoring the template loader function protocol (described briefly [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09/).)

Is it possible that one of your recent changes was to either `settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS` or to a custom template loader? If the latter, your template function needs an `is_usable` attribute, presumably set to `True`.

Comment: For the benefit of whoever next has this problem, what did you do?

Comment: I would like to know what he did as well, I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: @RobertAHenru Can you explain what you did to solve the problem?

Comment: For everybody else to know, it's solved by adding an ``is_usable`` attribute to the function and set it to ``True``. this is, when you are done writing your custom template loader function, you need to set: ``template_loader_function.is_usable = True``.